# How to set up and subsequently cancel multiple watchers in redux-sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Just trying to get my head around redux-sagas and running in to a problem setting up two watchers in a saga and then subsequently cancelling them.

Some background: I have a JSON Editor component where the saga handles calls to the backend API to load and save a JSON schema. The project is based on the [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/) and so the structure of the application is pretty much exactly the same.

Here is the relevant code:

```
export function* loadSchemaWatcher() {
  const action = yield take(LOAD_SCHEMA)
  yield call(loadSchema, action)
}

export function* saveSchemaWatcher() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(SAVE_SCHEMA)
    yield call(saveSchema, action)
  }
}

export function* editorData() {
  const watcher = yield [
    fork(loadSchemaWatcher),
    fork(saveSchemaWatcher)
  ]

  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE)
  yield watcher.forEach(task => cancel(task))
}

export default [
  editorData,
]
```

I assumed that `yield watcher.forEach(task => cancel(task))` would just loop over the array of [Tasks](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#task) but they aren't being cancelled.

Comment: Any reason not to simply run `yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE)` then both forks right after within `editorData()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code doesnt work because `forEach` returns undefined. You'll have to replace it with `map` which will return an array of cancel effects

```
yield watcher.map(task => cancel(task))
```

You can also use the `race` effect to cancel the whole array effect declaratively. Note that `fork` has been replaced with `call`

```
export function* editorData() {
  yield race([
    [
      call(loadSchemaWatcher),
      call(saveSchemaWatcher)
    ],
    take(LOCATION_CHANGE)
  ])
}
```

Comment: Why does eslint not like this? error: race must have on object hash as the only argument  redux-saga/no-yield-in-race